if high-spec telescope with a budget of over 1 million US dollars and aim it at a nearby star like Proxima Centauri, what will the image look like?
how image look like form that distance? and why? can james webb detect that star? I mean even hubble can detect near star likr proxima century light? but how like we see nearby star form james webb?

Gravitational lensing is our best chance of getting good quality-images of distant stars and planetary systems: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4d0EGIt1SPc It would be much better than any telescope we can dream of building.

At 4.2 light-year distance, any small-mass star is effectively a point source. The image created by a telescope will be produced by the telescope's aberrations.

A point source as imaged by a system with negative (top row), zero (middle row), and positive spherical aberration (bottom row).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_aberration

You should note that we can resolve the surface of a few relatively nearby humongous stars (other than the sun), although I'm sure this involves a lot of image processing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stars_with_resolved_images

@WaterMolecule ... the OP specified Proxima Centauri which is not humongous.
